# ios share data between users

Tags: iphone, ios, data-sharing

What is the best way to share data between users of the same app - like a shared list of items that only 2 specific users can see and edit.
My question is about the data transfer part - is there any service or framework I can use? I would like to avoid creating the server part myself.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you limit the content to 2 specific users? Username and passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to deal with your own server side implementation then you could use one of the PAS (platform as a service) providers like StackMob, Parse or Azure. They all offer persistent storage via a very simple iOS API. If your needs are simple, you can probably use StackMob for free. Something like Azure or Amazon will give you a lot more features and flexibility, but will cost money after the initial trial is over.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such thing. The closest you could get is in terms of API functionality are turn-based matches in Game Center, but the match data can be manipulated only in turns, and therefore this API most likely will not work for you. Running your own server given all those great offers from Google, Amazon, and others, is not a scary thing at all and will reward you with more flexibility.