# Best BAAS for sharing private database records between users?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cloudkit, mbaas

In essence, I'm building a private journaling app for iOS using Swift that will have a social feature. When creating a new entry, the user can choose to share the entry with specified friends from a friends list. The friend will receive a notification of the new entry, and it will be added to their own journal. The friend can later choose to accept or deny addition of the entry from their personal journal after review. Users won't be able to see each other's journals, they will only be able to share(add) entries to their friend's journals.

While I'd prefer to use iCloud, CloudKit won't allow me to share the entry records between users if I store them in a private database, and the information will be too sensitive to plop into the public database. CKRecordZones would be helpful, but they are only available for organizing a private database, so they will do me no good with sharing entries.

Can the privatized entry sharing I want be accomplished through Parse or perhaps another service I'm unaware of? Or will I have to build a custom backend to accomplish this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think below links can solve your problem:

[iOS 8 data sharing between users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014020/ios-8-data-sharing-between-users)

[How to share Core Data between multiple users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178031/how-to-share-core-data-between-multiple-users)

[ios share data between users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779936/ios-share-data-between-users)

Read all 3 questions and right answers of them.

Comment: Unfortunately none of those really help... I have been researching iCloud for a while now and can't seem to find a way to accomplish this there. I'm not as familiar with Parse so I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to accomplish it that way or with another service. I'm not comfortable at this point building my own backend, but if that's required here I can figure it out.

Comment: I guess for Parse you'll easily get demo and other required help.

Answer (score 0):

CloudKit would be the easiest when you are ok with limiting it to Apple devices only. If you wan tot make a quick start with that, then try out [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao)

Until now the logical choice for this kind of apps was Parse. It's easy to implement and has a lot of features.

Amazon just released a new [AWS Mobile Hub](http://techcrunch.com/2015/10/08/amazon-launches-aws-mobile-hub-to-help-mobile-developers-build-back-end-processes/) that looks very promising. It integrates with all AWS services, is very powerful and now also easy to use.

You could also use [Microsoft Azure Mobile Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/). It looks like it has similar features as AWS.

Of course there are more less known environments that also might work in your case but I think it would be wiser to stay with one of the above 4 well known choices.

Which of these you should pick is more or less a personal choice. They can all do what you want. If it's the best use for you depends on your use case.

Comment: I would really prefer to use iCloud, but I can't figure out how to keep the information secure. I think I will try Parse though. I found this link and it sounds like exactly what I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045977/privacy-settings-of-the-parse-com-anypic

Comment: CloudKit is secure by default. What someone can see depends on the query that you create yourself in your app. It all depends on the data structure and the queries that you will define yourself.

Comment: CloudKit would definitely be my first choice! Secure enough to store something as sensitive as financial records? I know from a visibility stand point, the users won't see all the information but I want to be sure someone can't easily hack my app and get their data.

Comment: A CloudKit container is linked to a developper account. Your application will also be linked to that developer account. Only an app that is published under the same developer account will be able to access that container. The only workaround for that is if you as a developer would hand out a token for someone else to use with the web api. As I said, security is completely in your hands. It all depends on the data structure and the queries that you use.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 'Until now[...]' phrase? Why isn't Parse the logical choice anymore? Thanks!

Comment: @JanApotheker AWS is pushing mobile at the moment. The services underneath are already well testes with lot's of functionality. With the new mobile dashboard it's now almost as easy to use as Parse. But then... it's still beta...